# How to skip nextLinks during initailization of delta query

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is there any way to skip processing nextLinks after the initialization of delta query for AD. Paging through it takes to much time and all I need is delta link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$deltaToken=latest` and the response will contain a `@odata.deltaLink`.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview).